# Loading Images and music Leads to not responding state for few seconds - kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a code which loads some images and music files for their usage in the code .

Problem is that it goes to not responding state for few seconds when i run program for the first time in windows , I know it should take some time to load images and music however i want to do that without going to not responding state but at a time when i can show a screen named loading  and on background all stuff gets loaded and once stuff is loaded program should go further .

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: Could you post a small example app reproducing this behavior? It would be a lot easier to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the splash screen visible, although I am new to kivy so I don't know how. In some SDK you can control when the screen disappears, you could make it disappear after your media are loaded. But sometimes this will mean too long a wait for UI to appear, in that case you are better off doing as @inclement suggests in [Remove or replace the kivy splash screen on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057647/remove-or-replace-the-kivy-splash-screen-on-startup):

> make sure your build method doesn't do much, and try to construct as much state as possible only after that.

You would typically load the media in a separate thread that you start from the GUI build method, and you have your thread signal load complete via a callback where you update GUI accordingly. I don't know yet if that is how one is meant to do it in kivy.