# Kivy Can I remove kivy loading screen when open app in android?

Tags: python, android, kivy

After deploy my android app created by using kivy to android. I open app it shows kivy loading screen before app open. Can I remove kivy loading screen from my app?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
 def build(self):
  return Label(text='Test')

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This screen is part of the python-for-android process, not something you can directly modify in your kivy app. However, you can change what image is displayed with the --presplash option for build.py. If using buildozer, you would instead set the presplash.filename token in your buildozer.spec file.

Something like `presplash.filename = 'image.png"`

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057647/remove-or-replace-the-kivy-splash-screen-on-startup) post: